# Django: FormView: How to add initial logic?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a FormView with some validations, all works fine. However, I'd like to add some initial logic that would immediately redirect to another view, based on some condition(s) I have. Something like this:

```
class UserFormView(FormView):
    template_name = 'pages_fixed/users/userform.html'
    form_class = UserForm

    def get(self, request):
        if condition:
            # if some condition met, want to immediately go to another URL..
            return redirect('/dashboard/')
        else:
           # condition not met, just display the form..
           return request

    def form_valid(self, form):
        # Form validates, code away...
```

I can't seem to make it work -- is the get() method not available in FormView? Since I can't pass more than two args into it, either I get infinite redirects or it's missing the form...

I know I can convert it to use a View but I'd really like to understand the difference. When is one better than the other? (So far, using FormView seems a lot faster -- in my experience whenever I do `return render(request, url)` Django takes a while..)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't return the request. You need to return the super's get result.

```
if condition:
    return redirect('/dashboard/')
else:
    return super(UserFormView, self).get(request)
```

Comment: Indeed! Now, I need to really look into what exactly happens here. Keep tripping on this same issue.. Thx!

Comment: It's just calling the FormView's get method. You can follow the trace by looking through the Django source. And you're welcome!